# Yet another JUNIT test with Spring -- Autowired not working question

Tags: java, spring, junit

Using spring and junit 4, I am trying to run a test that calls a class which has some other classes autowired, and yet I am getting NULL pointer exceptions.

I've done the

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:ecmdm-bulkdownload-context.xml"})
```

Added in @Autowired in the TEST class to try and trigger this, but no luck.

TEST class  (NOTE -- the @autowired here was to try and force the autowire, but that also didn't work....)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:ecmdm-bulkdownload-context.xml"})
public class BulkDownloadFileTransferTest {
    @Autowired
    BulkDownloadDao bulkDownloadDao;
    @Autowired
    BulkDownloadFileTransfer  bdFT;
    @Autowired
    BulkDownloadDefinition bulkDownloadDefinition;


    @Test
    public void testCreateFolderMapping1() {        

        bulkDownloadDefinition.setId("1");
        bulkDownloadDefinition.setSearchFilterTxt("{\"searchFilter\":[{\"id\":\"DocumentTitle\",\"name\":\"Document Title\",\"selectedOperator\":\"STARTSWITH\",\"value\":\"Bulk\"}],\"searchClass\":[{\"name\":\"Moodys Document\",\"objectType\":\"moodys_doc\",\"searchSubclasses\":true,\"andSearch\":true}]}");
        bulkDownloadDefinition.setGroupFilterTxt("mdy_org_id;Id;");
        bulkDownloadDefinition.setNetworkRequestId("302");      
        Message<BulkDownloadDefinition> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(bulkDownloadDefinition).build();       

        bdFT.createFolderMapping(message);


    }
...
...
```

The CLASS being tested:

```
ublic class BulkDownloadFileTransfer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BulkDownloadFileTransfer.class);

    @Autowired
    private BulkDownloadProperties bulkDownloadProperties;

    @Autowired
    private BulkDownloadDao bulkDownloadDao;
    /**
     * 
     * @param message
     * @return
     */
    public BulkDownloadDefinition createFolderMapping(Message<BulkDownloadDefinition> message) throws BulkDownloadException{

        LOGGER.debug("createFolderMapping() execution starts here");

        BulkDownloadDefinition bulkDownloadDefinition=message.getPayload();
        try{

        List<BulkDownloadNetworkBean> networkPathDetails=bulkDownloadDao.getNetworkPathDetails(bulkDownloadDefinition.getNetworkRequestId());

        BulkDownloadNetworkBean bulkDownloadNetworkBean=networkPathDetails.get(0);

...
...
```

The bulkDownloadDao is NULL when trying to run this.

Comment: This could happen if the BulkDownloadDao bean is not defined in ecmdm-bulkdownload-context.xml. But which BulkDownloadDao is null? In the test suite class, or in the class being tested? Also it is not clear why you are injecting it into the test class, it does not seem to be in use there, unless it is later down in the code.

Comment: I only added the injection in the test class to try and see if I could force it to wire (which also didn't work).  The BulkdDownloadDao IS in the file:  <bean id="bulkDownloadDao" class="com.moodys.ecmdm.bulkdownload.db.daoimpl.BulkDownloadDaoImpl">
  <!-- <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg> -->
 </bean>